# Exercise 4.3, Atiyah Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

> Let $A$ be an absolutely flat ring, i.e. any $A$-module is flat. Prove that any primary ideal $q\subset A$ is maximal.

I have an exact sequence of $A$-modules: $$0\to q\to A\to A/q\to 0.$$ My idea would be find an $A$-module $M$ that, tensorized with the sequence above, gives this sequence: $$0\to 0\to A/q\to k\to 0,$$ where $k$ is a field (and an $A$-module). My intuition was to use the ideal $1+q$, but I don't see any intelligent way to do it. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Your idea doesn't seem to use flatness, as flatness only gives you the leftmost $0\to0$ in your exact sequence. To use an idea like yours, I think you have to actively utilize the left side of some short exact sequence as well.

Comment: If $M$ wasn't flat I couldn't say that the second sequence is exact, so I couldn't say that $A/q\cong k$

Comment: If $M$ wasn't flat, you would still have $0\to A/q\to k\to 0$, but without the $0\to0$ on the left side. All tensor products are right exact, regardless of flatness.

Comment: At this point I should find $M$ such that $M\otimes q=q$, $M\otimes A=A$ and $M\otimes A/q$ is a field but I don't know if it's a good approach

Comment: No it's not good because I see that we would have $M=M\otimes A=A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exercise 2.27 (Atiyah-Macdonald p.35) says
$A$ is absolute flat iff every principal ideal is idempotent.

The problem can be  proved using only this fact.

Let $q$ be any primary ideal of  $R$. We will show $A/q$ is a field. Lex $x$ be any elements of $A$ which is not contained in $q$(This means $x$ is non-zero element in $A/q$). Then $(x)=(x^2)$. So for some $a$, $ax^2=x$,hence $x(ax-1)=0$. Since $x \notin q$ and $q$ is a primary ideal, there is some $n>0$ s.t. $(ax-1)^n \in q$ . Expanding $(ax-1)^n$ we know $1 -bx \in q$ for some $b \in A$. This means $x$ is  invertible in $A/q$. i.e. $A/q$ is a field so $q$ is a maximal ideal.

sorry for my poor English...